# How to keep minkube kube-apiserver from using up a tone of %CPU?

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage, minikube, kube-apiserver

After deploying anything to minikube it seems as though the apiserver starts eating up all the CPU and makes the dashboard mostly unusable until the apiserver dies and gets restarted.

I've read through a bit of the references found in this post: [kube-apiserver high CPU and requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394876/kube-apiserver-high-cpu-and-requests)

However, those seem to specifically target deployed k8s clusters on many machines, or at least where the master isn't on the same machine.

That's not how it would work with minikube since it's a signle node cluster.  Not to mention it typically isn't given a ton of resources (neither CPU or mem).

Is there a way to curb or eliminate this behavior?  Perhaps I've missed some important configuration for running on minikube?

Comment: How did you ensure kube-apiserver is actually the one eating CPU?

Comment: @Clorichel `top`  %CPU at ~150%+ for kube-apiserver on local instance.

Comment: How are you starting the minikube and what is being deployed?

Comment: @Crou I've seen this happen with as little as an nginx proxy container and a webserver while running filebeat getting zero traffic, of course, since it's running on a local machine.  I'm only starting it with the basic `minikube start` command (nothing special).

Comment: @lucidquiet have you tried starting `minikube` with more resources?

Comment: A bit late on this reply, but I have started using more resources to combat this behavior.  The machine can cope once I've upped the memory to 8gb, but might work with less, I just happen to have the extra ram.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I run almost empty minikube on 12 cores + 16 gb ram and kube-apiserver happily eats seven CPUs on idle configuration

Comment: The solution appears to be run with more than the defaults and update to newer minikube if possible.